# PhoneGap - How to add page transition effect without JQuery mobile in ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cordova

I am using simple `window.location` to navigate from one to another page.

How can i navigate page with slide effect using `window.location` ?

(Tried with JQuery mobile but its adding heavy page size and ui is disturbing in app.)

Can you please suggest on this ?

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use just jquery, and in the document.ready function use the effects from jquery library.

For eg :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("body").css("display", "none");
        $("body").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

If you give this on the page, the page will load very slowly and this just uses jquery library and no other plugin.

For redirecting :

```
$("a.transition").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    linkLocation = this.href;
    $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage(linkLocation));     
});

function redirectPage(link) {
    window.location = link;
}
```

Hope you get the idea.

You can see a complete and detailed explanation at  : http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/

Quick example : http://www.onextrapixel.com/examples/jquery-page-transitions/index.php

Answer (score 1):

If your looking for a sliding effect look into CSS3. It has easy to use Transition call that allows you to slide views around with very little code. For instance:

```
 //css
 .firstpage{
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 transition: all 2s;
}
 .movefirstpage{
 left:100%;
 }

 //js
 $(".firstpage").addClass(".movefirstpage");
```

Basically what this will do is slide the first page to the left off the screen. You can use the same logic to slide a new page onto the screen.

Also check out this link:
http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/03/hardware-accelerated-page-transitions-for-mobile-web-apps-phonegap-apps/